# jQuery - clicking on one element triggers another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

i have this jQuery file, but the `vote_up click handler` keeps conflicting with the `vote_down click handler`, when i click the vote_down element it changes the vote_up element:

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.vote_up").click(function () {
        //get the id
        var the_id = this.id.split('_').pop();
        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id=" + the_id,
            url: "ajax/votes.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("span.vote_count#" + the_id).html(msg).fadeIn();
                $("#" + the_id + " img").attr("src", "img/uparrowActive.png");
            }
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    // the vote down function
    $("a.vote_down").click(function () {
        //get the id
        var vote_id = this.id.split('_').pop();
        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_down&id=" + vote_id,
            url: "ajax/votes.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("span.vote_count#" + vote_id).html(msg).fadeIn();
                $("#" + vote_id + " img").attr("src", "img/downarrowActive.png");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<a href='#' class='vote_up' id="id_23"><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
<a href='#' class='vote_down' id="id_23"><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>
```

the jQuery and ajax request is wokring fine, but the change of src is the problem, because when i click vote down, it changes the vote_up image!!

Comment: all of that can go inside of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: getaway - See @Pointy's answer and memorize it. It has been mentioned a number of times in your previous questions. It is a very important rule that can not be overlooked. Sorry to be so blunt.

Comment: sorry im just so confused, this is my for my college project, so i must get it right, im such a newbie :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for some sort of strategy for focusing events to a repeating piece of data, utilizing IDs with the number appended to reference the various elements may work, but may not be the best approach.

I assume each repeating item has its own container that repeats. You may be better off placing a unique ID on that container, and finding the elements from there.

Take this for example:

```
<div id='outerContainer'>
    <div id='set_123' class='someContainer'>
        <a href='#' class='vote_up'><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
        <span class='vote_count'></span>
        <a href='#' class='vote_down'><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id='set_124' class='someContainer'>
        <a href='#' class='vote_up'><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
        <span class='vote_count'></span>
        <a href='#' class='vote_down'><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id='set_125' class='someContainer'>
        <a href='#' class='vote_up'><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
        <span class='vote_count'></span>
        <a href='#' class='vote_down'><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could [use `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to place click handlers on the `#outerContainer` that fire when you click the appropriate up/down elements.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outerContainer').delegate('.vote_up', 'click', function() {
       //get the id
        var the_id = $(this).closest('.someContainer').attr('id').split('_').pop();
        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              // Make sure "this" in the callback refers to the element clicked
            context: this,
            data: "action=vote_up&id=" + the_id,
            url: "ajax/votes.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                  // Not sure where your vote_count is. See the HTML for my placement
                $(this).siblings("span.vote_count").html(msg).fadeIn();
                  // get the child <img> and set its src
                $(this).children("img").attr("src", "img/uparrowActive.png");
            }
        });
    });
    $('#outerContainer').delegate('.vote_down', 'click', function() {
       //get the id
        var the_id = $(this).closest('.someContainer').attr('id').split('_').pop();
        //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              // Make sure "this" in the callback refers to the element clicked
            context: this,
            data: "action=vote_down&id=" + the_id,
            url: "ajax/votes.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                  // Not sure where your vote_count is. See the HTML for my placement
                $(this).siblings("span.vote_count").html(msg).fadeIn();
                  // get the child <img> and set its src
                $(this).children("img").attr("src", "img/downarrowActive.png");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So the ID with the number you need is on each `.someContainer`. You traverse up to that container to get the ID, and do your `.split().pop()`.

Then in the AJAX request, I set [the `context:` property for `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) so that `this` will still refer to the element that was clicked in your callback.

Inside the callback, you find [the `.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) that have the class `.vote_count`, and set [its `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) content.

Finally you [use `.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to get the `img` element, and set its `src` attribute.

This should give the general idea. You'll need to adjust for your HTML.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have chnaged evrything to fit my html, but i tried to read about the context bit, but i dnt get it, im already sending the ajax to votes.php aint i, i was thinking shall i put this `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: @getaway - I don't understand your last sentence, but with regard to context, the reason I added that property to the AJAX request is because *inside the callback* I wanted `this` to refer to the element that was clicked. When you have an AJAX callback, like your `success:` callback, the meaning of `this` magically changes inside the callback, so that it no longer refers to the element that was clicked. To make it refer to that element once again, you pass `this` via the `context:` property of the request. That's only one approach, but is probably the cleanest.

Comment: ...if I hadn't done that, `$(this).siblings(...` and `$(this).children(...` would have not worked, because `this` would no longer be a reference to the `.vote_up` or `.vote_down` element that was clicked.

Comment: @getaway - What do you mean by "remove the context"? In the code I posted, I want `this` to refer to the element that was clicked for the `success:` callback. If I don't have `context:this`, it will not. In other words, *before* the AJAX request (in the click handler), `this` is a reference to the element that was clicked. But *inside* the `success:` callback for the AJAX request, `this` no longer refers to that element. But we want it to. So setting the `context:` property to `this` makes it so that `this` continues to be a reference to the element in the callback.

Comment: oh my god patrick, what about if i wanted to implent a toggle on the votes, basically reverse the action, just like stackoverflow! i was thinking i have to create another script obviously dealing with reverse votes!! :))

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the same "id" value for two different elements.

Comment: @getaway - You can change it to `van_halen_1984` if you want, as long as it is unique. :o)

Comment: Things will improve if you change it to something other than "id_23".  An "id" value **must** be unique across the whole page if you want things to work properly. That's what it's called "id" ("identity").

Comment: I always thought it was 'identification'?

Comment: now the whole jquery thing is not working only the ajax bit? :(( i think i need to go to sleep

Comment: @colinmarc well whatever; something that means "unique in all the world like a perfect snowflake or a precious duck baby".

Comment: @Peter - Oh, it could've been [so much worse](http://dietrichthrall.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/poison_group.jpg). :o)